# size in KB for a field in sql fields

Tags: sql, db2

I would appreciate if someone can let me know the way to find out the size of any field in KB which is returned as a result of Sql query.

For example

```
Select x,y from table A
```

Result -

```
x   y
x1  y1y1y1y1y1y1
x2  y2y2y2...........long string character.
x3  y3y3y3y3.........Long string character.
-
-
-
-
```

I am looking for

```
x       y
x1      10kb - Size of ( y1y1y1..) in kb
x2      100kb- Size of (y2y2y2...) in kb
```

any help/suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT x, LENGTH(y) 
FROM table_name
```

[Some caveats about multibyte characters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.char/src/tpc/db2z_specifylengthcalcutation.htm). If you're using multibyte characters, think about using the [VARCHAR() function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.char/src/tpc/db2z_specifylengthcalcutation.htm) instead of LENGTH().

For length in kilobytes, divide LENGTH(Y) by 1024.

```
SELECT x, LENGTH(y)/1024.0 
FROM table_name
```